# How to prevent Child models from Deletion in Golang GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Well, I would like to know, Is there any solutions, how to prevent Child Model from deletion in foreignKey Constraint, (

For example in `gorm` there is a couple of options that allows to restrict behavior of the Parent Model after deletion, and Delete or Set to Null the Child Model Objects That has foreignKey relation (onDelete: Cascade / Set Null, and the same thing for onUpdate)

// Pretty a lot of the same words, but I hope you got it :)

Little Example.. from Golang ...

```
type SomeOtherStruct struct {
     gorm.Model
     Id int 

} 

type SomeModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    someOtherStructId string 

    someField SomeOtherStruct `gorm:"foreignKey:SomeOtherStructId; OnDelete:Cascade,OnUpdate: SET NULL"` // basically foreign Key Relationship to model `SomeOtherStruct`
}
```

But I would like to prevent any Update/Deletion behavior, so Child Relation Models Objects won't get deleted after the Parent Model Object has been..

There is actually a concept from Django Framework (Python)

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
     
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(to=AnotherModel,   verbose_name="SomeField", on_delete=models.PROTECT) 

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
     pass
```

As you can see, there is `models.PROTECT` constraint, that is basically what I'm looking for....

Is there any analogy for that in Golang GORM or some `RAW SQL` for that as well?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't mention which database you are using.

In Postgres (as an example) there are multiple options for `ON DELETE`:

- `NO ACTION`
- `RESTRICT`
- `CASCADE`
- `SET NULL`
- `SET DEFAULT`

Only `CASCADE` will delete children if the parent is deleted. All other options (including the default `NO ACTION`) will make sure the children will "survive".

You can find more information in the postgres documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Please feel free to update your question and/or comment with the database you are using.